How to get CancellationToken to trigger, on Docker Container SIGTERM?
In C# .NET 8, I have...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .RegisterSharedServices()
    .Services
        .AddSingleton<..., ...>();

// Add Controllers
builder
    .AddCoreApiSupport() // that's custom
    . ...();

// Host
builder
    .Services
        .AddHostedService<CoreBackgroundService>();

var webApp = builder.Build();

...


webApp.SetupApiSupport();

await webApp.RunAsync();

type of the project is <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">.
So essentially I am running a BackgroundService implementation with an API Support on top of it, in a Linux Docker Container.
I want to capture and handle the SIGTERM signal, by the means of CancellationToken which is propagated everywhere. Its "entry point" is here, in the implementation of the class deriving from BackgroundService:
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)

It baffles me that stoppingToken is never triggered (i.e. a Task.Delay(...) wouldn't throw an exception, for example. It seems like the signal is completely ignored, when I shut the container down from Docker Desktop. I've read something about requiring RunConsoleAsync and a Console Lifetime Support, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.
My question is - what do I need to change, so that my CancellationToken gets triggered on Docker Container shut down?
I've tried this too:
appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stopping!");
});

for what it's worth, I never get the Console.WriteLine(...) to execute. Not sure what that means, it's like if the ApplicationStopping event never triggers.

Shouldn't you just override StopAsync?

How do you stop your container?

are you aware of this question?

I stop the container using the Stop button on Docker Desktop. Ok, I've overridden StopAsync and it did nothing for me. Not to mention the confusion between the two different CancellationToken, one in StopAsync and one in ExecuteAsync.

I don't think I should be overriding StopAsync, see this.

I think I know what the problem is - the use of Debug mode in VS2022. According to other posts on SO, it uses optimizations, which prevents the CancellationToken from triggering. I will post it as an answer, when I figure out how to make the Release mode take into consideration my other nugget sources.

Have a look at Issue This may be of some interest.
